# Mosquitto ends up with "Error: Address not available"

Tags: docker, mqtt, mosquitto

I hope you can help me, I'm so desperate.

No matter what I change, I just can't make MQTT work for me:

```
1668546676: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
1668546676: Starting in local only mode. Connections will only be possible from clients running on this machine.
1668546676: Create a configuration file which defines a listener to allow remote access.
1668546676: For more details see https://mosquitto.org/documentation/authentication-methods/
1668546676: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1668546676: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1668546676: Error: Address not available
1668546676: mosquitto version 2.0.15 running
```

Here is my docker-compose.yaml

```
 mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    container_name: mosquitto
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /opt/mosquitto/conf:/mosquitto/conf
      - /opt/mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
      - /opt/mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
      - "9001:9001"
```

And my mosquitto.conf

```
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
log_dest stdout
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
```

I've seen a lot of similar errors, but their solutions never worked for me. What's wrong there? What should I try? MQTT integration is not working in Home Assistant because of the unavailable address. It always ends up with a "Failed to connect" message.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Where is your `mosquitto.conf` file (according to the `docker-compose.yml` it should be at `/opt/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf`)? The log output implies that your modified config file has not been loaded by mosquitto inside the contianer.

Comment: OMG, I'm an idiot. I renamed the directory and all mentions of "conf" to "config" and it works now. I kept looking for a problem in ports, firewall, etc., but the solution was in front of my face. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments.

Incorrect path for the mounted config file volume. It should be:

```yaml
mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    container_name: mosquitto
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /opt/mosquitto/conf:/mosquitto/config 
      - /opt/mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
      - /opt/mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
      - "9001:9001"
```